# Pandas dataframe computations

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying compute a metric with panda dataframes. In particular, I get a results object

```
prediction = results.predict(start=1,end=len(test),exog=test)
```

The actual values are in a dataframe given by

```
test['actual'].
```

I need to compute two things:

1. How can I compute the sum of squares of errors? So basically, I would be doing an element by element subtraction and then summing the squares of these.
2. How can I compute the sum of squares of the predicted minus the mean of the actual values? So it would be

   ```
   (x1-mean_actual)^2 + (x2-mean_actual)^2...+(xn-mean_actual)^2
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First one would be

```
((prediction - test['actual']) ** 2).sum()
```

Second one would be:

```
((prediction - test['actual'].mean()) ** 2).sum()
```

Comment: I get a nan value for the first one. What does that imply?

Comment: do you have any NaN in your data?

Comment: I think these should be .sum()

Comment: @AndyHayden AFAIK, `sum(...)` will be slower than `.sum()`? is it possible to do it right with `np.sum(...)`?